Could not find method classpath() flutter
buildscript {
    repositories{
        google()        
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {        
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'

subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Exception: 

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Also please format your buildscript code more legibly.  It's all on one line, make it very hard to read.

classpath is not a valid configuration to declare dependencies on.
In a buildscript { ... } block classpath would exist as a configuration to add dependencies to the build script for usage in the build script code, though even there it is bad practice to use it.
If you need that dependencies for your code, you probably want to use implementation instead.
I also recommend switching to Kotlin DSL. By now it is the default DSL, you immediately get type-safe build scripts, actually helpful error messages if you mess up the syntax, and amazingly better IDE support if you use a good IDE like IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio.
